# View offset by navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar

I have a place profile set up that displays place information in a nib. When I push this view in the standard screen flow it works fine. However when I push this view from another tab the UINavigationBar seems to offset it please see image here - http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/525/screenshot20111006at225.png/ I think it may be the navigation bar going over the view however I'm not sure how to correct this.

Comment: Set the `self.view.frame` size from 44 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Interface Builder, make sure the view is autosizing and you've turned on the Navigation Bar in "Simulated Metrics", so that the top Y coordinate is 44 as opposed to zero. Oh, and make sure your navigation bar isn't set to Black Translucent, but Black Opaque.
2. To manually correct, set `self.view.bounds` to the right co-ordinates in your featured view's [`viewWillAppear`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear%3a) or [`viewDidLoad`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad) (if you use manual coordinates, `viewDidLoad` is fine, but I think you need `viewWillAppear` if you're using parts of `self.navigationController` like the position of `navigationBar`). For example:

   ```
   - (void) viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 367); // assuming tabbar+navbar
   }
   ```

Comment: this didn't apear to work. The View is not offset in the other tab its just offset in the featured tab :S how would I set self.view.bounds?

Comment: You need to implement in the view controller class one of the methods I stated above. I'll add links to the documentation for those methods.